# Rails ActiveRecord hash condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hash

I really don't understand some tutorial code despite running the equivalents of it on a console (which don't work) and there's no explanation.

This comes from the Rails guides and I really like to understand everything that I read

```
Article.where(author: author)
Author.joins(:articles).where(articles: { author: author })
```

The (author: author) part is where I get lost. I mean does it do a self join? If that's the case I can't do it on my console with the same syntax.

And if author: author means articles.author and Author.author (which would be weird because ambiguity.

Thanks, sorry if this has been posted before.

Comment: On a side note if the tutorial you read this from has comments, it's worth highlighting your confusion to the author, they *should* appreciate the feedback and you may help others falling into the same confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Article.where(author: author)
```

^- Select Article records by the given author.

Select Article records where the author_id (probably) column equals the "id of author". Now `author` (after the :) could be a local variable or it could be a method call returning an 'author' object. Either way, it's probably an instance of an Author model class that responds to an `id` method call.

```
Author.joins(:articles).where(articles: { author: author })
```

^- Select Author records for authors that have an Article. Again the `author` here (after the :) is a local variable or a method call. The `articles: { author: author }` is just a convenient way to put some criteria on the join.

Once you get the correct `author` variable sorted, add a `.to_sql` to the end of the method call chain in your console to see what SQL is being generated. That should help you understand what's going on.

Comment: I used article as an instance of an Article model and it kind of worked. The SQL says it worked but I can't see the comments as part of the "joined table". I can by calling a.comments but I could do that before. But thanks for your comment is works and I at least understand enough to not let me bother me.

Comment: It might be worth editing your question to expand on what you are doing around those ActiveRecord calls if some more explanation would help…